# How do I compare a local git branch with a remote git branch with this setup?

Tags: git, github

Given the below branches, I tried to compare with `git diff mybranch remotes/origin/mybranch` but it shows an empty diff even though i know there are changes.

The branches returned from `git branch -a`:

```
  master
* mybranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD - > origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mybranch
```

What should the command be? Do I need to fetch first? (And if so, can I undo a fetch?)

Comment: Fetch won't merge anything locally, so yes, run that first if you're convinced you're out of sync with remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remotes/origin/mybranch` is a local copy of the remote branch. If you want to have the latest changes you need to fetch. A fetch will not modify your local branches, just the remote branches in your local repository, so it should not be necessary to undo the fetch.

If you really need to undo the fetch, you can easily do it with a `reset` and the reflog of the remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

Without doing a `fetch`, your computer will not know the contents of the remote branch.

`git fetch` will bring all the commits from the remote branch to your computer, but because all the commits have their own separate unique identifiers, you will always be able to *undo* the fetch by using `checkout`.